# Heroku SSL connection failure with MongoDB resulting in H10 ("app crashed") Heroku error. Obvious solutions re: Node.js environment failed so far

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

My application builds successfully, but the deployed site is inoperable. Heroku logs reveal an H10 error and a message indicating an SSL connection error with my MongoDB database. I'm using a MERN stack for this project – of key relevance, a Node.js environment that lives in a ./server directory in my root project folder. This simple db connection file – ./server/db/conn.js – has functioned correctly so far, using Mongoose ODM:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.connection;
```

And my server config file – ./server/server.js – also hasn't produced issues:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const result = dotenv.config();

if (result.error) {
  console.error("Dotenv config ERROR:", result.error);
} else {
  console.log("Dotenv config successful.");
}

const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const db = require("./db/conn");
const routes = require("./routes");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
}

app.use(routes);

db.once("open", () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(` Now listening on localhost:${PORT}`));
});
```

My first response was to check my Heroku env variables. The MondoDB URI string is correct, and is entered with key ATLAS_URI to match my code. I then tried a few additions, adding a procfile and amending my package-json to specify my node version under the "engines" param. These didn't help, and I've removed the changes for the time being since I haven't needed them in the past. I then realized I'd forgotten to give the Heroku IP access to my MongoDb cluster, so I fixed that (whitelisted all IP's for now) and thought surely that'd be it. But I'm still out of luck, everything is pushed and up to date and I still get the same error. Why won't they talk to each other?